# JMS with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, jms, completable-future, request-response

I'm stuck when using Java's `CompletableFuture` with JMS (ActiveMQ). When I send a request for which I expect a reply, I create a `CompletableFuture` and put that in a `Map` with the correlation ID as key.

This works perfectly *as long as I get a reply*. When I don't get a reply, zombie start to pile up in the map.

I tried to attach cleanup code to `CompletableFuture` using `whenComplete()` but the code isn't called at all when `CompletableFuture.get(long,TimeUnit)` times out (the Java code in `timedGet()` will just throw the exception without calling anything else).

This looks like such an obvious place to use the `Future` API. Does someone have a working example or an idea how to clean up dead entries in the map?

Note: It can take up to three hours until the response arrives.
Note 2: Java 8

Comment: Sorry for the first edit, I thought you were asking for an answer within 3h!  I changed the last sentence to avoid this confusion. As to the question itself, are you on java-8, or a more recent version? Because you might make use of [orTimeout()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) introduced in Java 9. Otherwise I think you should implement a similar feature yourself.

Comment: @DidierL Thanks for clearing that up. I'm looking at orTimeout() now.